# Problem in loading library for VIM package

Tags: r

Using R version R.4.0.3. Already installed the VIM package. When I try to load the library function as library(VIM), it fails to load and gives me the following error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘VIM’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
> undefined exports: as_factor, fct_anon, fct_c, fct_collapse, fct_count, fct_cross, fct_drop, fct_expand, fct_explicit_na, fct_infreq, fct_inorder, fct_inseq, fct_lump, fct_lump_lowfreq, fct_lump_min, fct_lump_n, fct_lump_prop, fct_match, fct_other, fct_recode, fct_relabel, fct_relevel, fct_reorder, fct_reorder2, fct_rev, fct_shift, fct_shuffle, fct_unify, fct_unique, first2, last2, lvls_expand, lvls_reorder, lvls_revalue, lvls_union
> In addition: Warning message:
> S3 methods ‘as_factor.character’, ‘as_factor.factor’, ‘as_factor.logical’, ‘as_factor.numeric’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found

Comment: try `remove.packages("VIM")` and the install it with `dependencies = TRUE` (if that's not how you installed it). This is what I would try, not really sure it will work.

Comment: Thank you. Removed it and installed it as install.packages("VIM,dependencies=TRUE). Still giving the same error for library(VIM).  Library(VIM) is working fine in my other (older) desktop. I guess it is related to this new computer. Best.